# sort the dataframe based on the time and keep the ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to sort it based on the time. But I want to keep the id constant.  Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
df['val'] = [10, 15, 12, 13, -1]
df['date'] = ['2023-02-23 22:15:00','2023-02-23 22:00:00','2023-02-24 22:15:00','2023-02-23 22:15:00','2023-02-23 21:15:00' ]
    id  val     date
0   1   10  2023-02-23 22:15:00
1   1   15  2023-02-23 22:00:00
2   1   12  2023-02-24 22:15:00
3   2   13  2023-02-23 22:15:00
4   2   -1  2023-02-23 21:15:00
```

I want the output be like:

```
    id  val     date
0   1   15  2023-02-23 22:00:00
1   1   10  2023-02-23 22:15:00
2   1   12  2023-02-24 22:15:00
3   2   -1  2023-02-23 21:15:00
4   2   13  2023-02-23 22:15:00
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covert to datetime and then `sort_values`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])

   id  val                date
1   1   15 2023-02-23 22:00:00
0   1   10 2023-02-23 22:15:00
2   1   12 2023-02-24 22:15:00
4   2   -1 2023-02-23 21:15:00
3   2   13 2023-02-23 22:15:00
```